# Resources to learn WebRTC / Streaming Protocols ( RTMP, HLS )

Tags: video-streaming, webrtc

I am just wondering if there is any good resources, books to learn WebRTC / Video Streaming (RTMP, HLS ) that protocols in depth.

With the current situation, these technologies are on-demand and trying to understand more to be able to debug issues better and find ways to improve.

Answer (score 1):

For webrtc there is https://webrtccourse.com/
(disclaimer: I'm involved with one of the courses)